# how to parse a row after reading it using unix shell

Tags: shell, unix, string-parsing

csv file with the first row has header file. I need to read this first row and then parse it to see if it has the elements i'm looking for. 
First row has 4 elements. 1. HDR 2. today's date 3. From date 4. To date.

here is the code i used to get the first row.

```
read -r header < "1" -- this game me the first row into header variable.
```

I tried to read this 'header' variable to further split the row.

```
read f1 f2 f3 < “$header”
        echo "OS is     : $f1"
        echo "Company is: $f2"
        echo "Value is  : $f3"
```

i'm getting no values displayed. I think the reason could be 'header' is not coming in as a string.

I'm new to unix shell scripting. Please help.

Comment: What is in `$header`? Did you start your script with `#!/bin/bash -vx` during debugging? Why don't you use [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) ? Please edit your question to improve it...

Comment: You don't show your entire script and its input. Please edit and improve your question to make some [MCVE]

Comment: Aside from the other comments which you already got, one more remark: I don't know how the lines you want to parse look like, but except for some special cases, POSIX shell isn't very convenient for string parsing (for instance, no regular expressions available). I suggest that you switch to some other shell (I prefer Zsh, but I think bash would be useful here too), or switch to some completely different programming language (Ruby, Perl, awk, Python, ....).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> read -r header < "1"
> ```

No. You are reading from a file named `1` (which probably does not exist, so `read` is failing) because `<` is used for [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)). Try typing that very command in a terminal, you'll get an error ("no such file or directory").

> ```
> read f1 f2 f3 < “$header”
> ```

This is wrong. If the `header` shell variable contains `1 2 3` you are reading from the file named `1 2 3`  (a six character file path with two spaces inside) because `<` is used for [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing))

Consider using [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) to process files made of lines containing several columns.

Consider starting your (executable) shell script with `#!/bin/bash -vx` (to get traces) during the debugging phase. Spend a few hours reading some [shell scripting tutorial](https://www.shellscript.sh/) and then the [bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/).

Be sure to understand how shells [work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398464/50557), notably their [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). Be aware that every program (e.g. started by some shell) is started by [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (done in some [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), e.g. your shell process).

BTW, before the `read f1 f2 f3 < “$header”` you might (temporarily) add debugging outputs, e.g.

```
 echo "header=" "$header" > /dev/stderr
```

in your shell script, to understand what is going on.

<sup>(You really should spend *days* in reading more about shells)</sup>